# Is there a Vim plugin for testing VimScript patterns?

Tags: vimscript, plugin, pattern

I'm new to VimScript and trying to learn how to construct patterns.

Is there a Vim plugin like [RegExr.com](https://regexr.com/) for testing patterns?

Comment: what is wrong with using `:set incsearch` and just trying it out interactively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very simple way, for which you do not need any plugin. Open a file with some content, turn on [`:set incsearch`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27incsearch%27) and/or [`:set hlsearch`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27hlsearch%27) and try it out interactively with Vim.

That's how you learn best, using the tools that you have available.

Answer (score 1):

The [trace](https://github.com/markonm/traces.vim) provide you a preview of the substitution and privide a good help to learn regular expression patterns.

If you are using Neovim you could also be interested by [hypersonic](https://github.com/tomiis4/hypersonic.nvim)